# Maildrop, deliver: on which criteria do you choose between them?

Tags: dovecot, email

Since Dovecot can handle both of them, is there a better choice than another in terms of performance, syntax, possibilities... ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with deliver has it provides you with mailbox indexing, sieve and quota support